# Get link source of Firefox history pages where vist_type is from a link?

Tags: sqlite, firefox, browser-history

Trying to parse Firefox history and I can't seem to find any information in the sqlite database that allows me to figure out what the source page in history is for another page when that page indicates it was opened from a link.

The relevant table is moz_historyvisits which has a column indicating the access type of the visit (vist_type) (link, search bar, external application, etc...) but it doesn't seem have a column/field that links back to the source.

Is there anyway to get this info or does Firefox not record it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a column in moz_historyvisits called "from_visit" which gives you the id of the row which is the source.